# Access element of an Array and return a monad?

Tags: scala, monads

If I access an index outside the bounds of an `Array`, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, eg:

```
val a = new Array[String](3)
a(4)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
```

Is there a method to return a monad instead (eg: Option)? And why doesn't the default collections apply method for Array support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`lift`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction):

```
a.lift(4) // None
a.lift(2) // Some(null)
```

`Array[T]` is a `PartialFunction[Int, T]` and `lift` creates a `Function[Int, Option[T]]` from the index to an option of the element type.

Comment: Your answer is too damn fast

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scala.util.Try`:

```
scala> val a = new Array[String](3)
a: Array[String] = Array(null, null, null)

scala> import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Try

scala> val fourth = Try(a(3))
third: scala.util.Try[String] = Failure(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
: 3)

scala> val third = Try(a(2))
third: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(null)
```

Another good idea is not using Array in the first place, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Where it is relevant to your question though is why this behaviour. Array is intended to function like a Java array and be compatible with a Java Array. Since this is how Java arrays work, this is how Array works.